# Jack and webcam videorecording

Tags: webcam, vlc, jack, cheese

Is there any means to record sound and video from the webcam and microphone while jack is operating?

Cheese stops recording when I start jack.

VLC can output in jack and apparently record sound with jack (with "JACK Audio Connection Kit" in "Capture mode"), but I do not know if it can record jack sound and video on the same time (the "Video for Linux 2" just suggests the "hw:0,0" option).

With guvcview I see "HDA Intel...", "pulse" and "default" as options in "Input Device" under Audio without jack, but I have had no luck with jack.

Answer (score 1):

Stumbling on a YouTube video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4_z_Cje_zls) with a brief note I found one solution to be to install the pulseaudio plugin for jack. This is mentioned on: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1768036

```
sudo apt-get install pulseaudio-module-jack
```

and with this text

```
pacmd load-module module-jack-source channels=2; pacmd load-module module-jack-sink channels=2;
```

in qjackctl > Setup > Options > Execute script after Startup

After this setup and with jack running "Sound settings" should show a "Jack source (PulseAudio JACK Source)" in Input and a "Jack sink (PulseAudio JACK Sink) in Output that can be selected. Cheese will now be able to record video and sound while jack is running.